# Telegram bot how to make answering to the questions via webhook c#

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

for example user command /userinfo  which send questions like 
Your  firstname ?
Your  lastname ?
etc

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Bot Framework provides state of the art bot development for many social networks and messaging platforms like Telegram. ChatBot development is very simple using Azure Bot Framework, There is a concept of dialog which allows the bot to ask questions from the user in a context.

Find documentation of Azure Bot Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-quickstart

Integrating Telegram bot with Bot Framework:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-telegram